# Selecting database inside the js in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I can run the script in the specific database like

```
 mongo main myscript.js<br/>
```

where     `main` is a database name. The same thing I am unable to run inside the script like

#### myscript.js

```
 use main;   // not taking, throw error when using "mongo myscript.js"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this in your script

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('main');
```

The default DB is `test`. This statement gets a "sibling" database of `test`.